# Inner Sql for Update Not working Mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a table with following columns

`CommentId`

`ParentCommentId`

`ChildCommentCount`

```
Update PostComment t1
set ChildCommentCount = (select count(*) from PostComment t2 where t2.CommentId = t1.ParentCommentId);
```

**Trying to update ChildCommentCount with total count of  where current CommentId shows up as a parent**

but this sql above gvies me error like

> Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 't1' for update in
>   FROM clause

any ideas how to rewrite this sql?

Comment: there's some workaround using joins, but like the error says, you can't use a table as a source of data while you're simultaneously trying to update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't select same table while you are updating it this can be done by using join

```
Update PostComment t1
join (
select CommentId ,count(*) total from PostComment group by CommentId 
) t2 on(t2.CommentId = t1.ParentCommentId)
set t1.ChildCommentCount = t2.total
```